# PowerShell - Unable to Search for [LIKE] File Names recursively through sub-directories

Tags: powershell, search, regexp-like

I have a list of a few hundred files that I need to search for.  Most do NOT have file extensions, some do.  I can separate those and run the job multiple times if I have to.

I have a script that I have been trying to get right and it Does not seem to work.
I need to match on just the file names and NOT the extensions.
I'm using the "-Like" option but that is not getting me the results I need.  If I include a file extension then it works.  Unfortunately I have many file names with unknown extensions and I need to match on just the name.

Also, the script does not seem to be scanning the sub-directories for matches.  Does -Recurse not work in my example?

And Finally, when testing and I FORCE a match, it does not display the subdirectory the match was found in.

Any assistance would be most welcome.
Regards,
-Ron

```
#Start in this DIR
 $folder = 'C:\Workspace\' 
#Get the file list here
 $Dir2 = 'C:\Workspace\'
 $files=Get-Content $Dir2\MISSING_BMS.txt

    Write-Host "Starting Folder: $folder"
    # Get only files and only their names
    $folderFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder -File -Name
    #Read through Directory and sub-directories
       foreach ($f in $files) {
          if ($folderFiles -contains $f) { 
            Write-Host "File $f was found." -foregroundcolor green
        } else { 
            Write-Host "File $f was not found!" -foregroundcolor red 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s **`-Name` switch doesn't just output *names* when combined with `-Recurse`, it outputs *relative paths*** for items located inside subdirectories.

Therefore, it is better not to use this switch and compare against the `.Name` *property* of the [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances that `Get-ChildItem` emits by default.

```
# Get only files and only their names - note the use of (...).Name
$folderFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder -File).Name
```

Note that if your `$Dir2\MISSING_BMS.txt` file contains *verbatim* file names rather than *wildcard patterns*, you should use the [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) operator rather than `-like`, the [wildcard matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like).

Also, if you need to access the full paths later:

```
# Get the files as [System.IO.FileInfo] instances
$folderFileInfos = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder -File

# ...

# Access the .Name property now, using member enumeration, and see 
# if the array of names contains $f
if ($folderFileInfos.Name -contains $f) { ...
```

Comment: That works!  I'll alter my code above to reflect the changes you suggested.  
Thank you very much!

-Ron